# Copying a file to HDFS2 via camel doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, apache-camel, hdfs

Does anyone have a good example of writing files to hdfs2 via camel?

I tried the following code :

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public final class Main {

    private Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("file:C:\\FILES\\SRC\\2015-03-31_16-58-56.png?noop=true")
                        .to("hdfs2://xxxx:9000/testCamel/D2/qwe.png");
                        //.to("file:C:\\FILES\\OUT");
            }
        });
        //ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

        context.start();

        context.stop();
    }
}
```

The files are created in HDFS but all of them are empty (0 bytes).

Comment: Could you add some details on your problem (by editing your question)? Do you get an exception or is the file just not copied ?

Comment: In my Hadoop files are created, but they are 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

make sure noop=false when you consume from a file to HDFS.  hdfs component uses chunk to consume, so if noop is true, camel will think that it already consumed it.